# Get token from storage Ionic (Async data)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to access token stored in cellphone storage, since this is obtained asynchronously.The variable is always undefined.

This is the .ts where I want to get the data.

cars.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ServiceRestProvider } from '../../providers/service-rest/service-rest';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController} from "ionic-angular";


@Component({
  selector: 'page-data',
  templateUrl: 'data.html'
})
export class ResumenCooperativaPage {
  cars: any;
  constructor(public service: SProvider,
    public loadingController: LoadingController) {
    this.getData();

  }

  getData() {
    this.service.getCars()
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (data.error) {
          console.log(data.error);
        } else {
          this.cars = data;
        }
      });         
  }
}
```

This is the service ts where I want to access the token first and then to see it. The token variable is always show undefined.
service.ts

```
getToken(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.get('Token').then((val) => {   
        resolve(val);  
        console.log('Your token is', val);  
      }); 
    });
  }

    getCars() {
      this.data= this.getToken();
      const hd = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.data)
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.data);
     return this.http.get(url, { headers: hd})
      .map((response) => {
          return response;
      });  
  }
```

Update:

Message after the changes :

```
[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

getCars() {
      this.getToken().then(token=>{
          this.data = token;
          const hd = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.data).set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.data);
          return this.http.get(url, { headers: hd}).map((response) => {
          return response;
      }); 
  })     
 }
```

[Void](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSSI3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright since your code is hard to understand I wanted to share with you how I would organize it please note that I don't yet know which http module you are using and there is a difference between modern (4.3+ angular) module and old one. I wrote the below having the modern one in mind:

in your rest-service.ts (provider that you will import into your components):

```
// do all of your specific imports here:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";

@Injectable()
export class RestService {

    // cache token here to use in your restful calls:
    userToken: string;

    constructor (

    ) {
      // obtain token once during service instantiation, service providers don't have lifecycle hooks but it is OK to do init values inside the constructor:
      this.getToken();
    }

    // this will get called once with constructor execution:
    getToken() {
      this.storage.get('Token').then((token) => {   
        this.userToken = token; 
      }); 
    };

    getCars() {
      // depending on your HTTP module used in Ionic (Angular < 4.3 or > 4.3):
      // only set Authorization property in header once:
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.userToken);
      // so http requests will return observables (if Angular 4.3 HttpClient module is used), you will subscribe to it in your components:
      return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers})
    }

}
```

Now in your cars.ts:

```
// do your proper imports here:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestService } from '../../app/providers/rest-service';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  // component var that will get assigned values:
  cars: Array<string> = [];

  constructor(public restService: RestService, public loadingController: LoadingController) {

  }
  // this life cycle hook is only called once when component enters memory, feel free to use other hooks as needed for your app, but key thing is that you call method in provider and subscribe/unsubscribe in components.
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // here on component load into memory you can call the method:
    this.restService.getCars().subscribe((carsData) => {
        this.cars = carsData;
      }, (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });  
  }

}
```

Your template can be this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Cars Page!</h2>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let car of cars">
      <ion-label>{{ car.title }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergei, I made the changes and it just shows me a message [ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'. in the function getdata(). And if possible, I would like you to help me with persistence on init, please.

Comment: @Allan which version of Angular are you using? Can you share how http module is imported in your app.module.ts?

Comment: My module is import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; in App.module.ts and my versión of Angular is 5.2.11, Ionic 3

Comment: Then my code in the answer should work for you. If any issues - ping me here but also share your imports AFTER you add my code also outlining what errors you see. I wrote this code in absence of ability to test it.